# What is the default value of res (resolution) in R's png function?

Tags: r, plot, png

What is the default value of the `res` parameter in `png()` ?

It can be changed like so `png(res = 200)`, but I'm not sure what it's default value is.

Oddly, it's not in the documentation produced when `?png` is run

i.e.

> res    The nominal resolution in ppi which will be recorded in the
>   bitmap file, if a positive integer. Also used for units other than the
>   default, and to convert points to pixels.

And (also strangely) the function itself does't even appear to be listed among those in the `grDevices` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.5.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is `72ppi` as stated in:

> res
>   The nominal resolution in ppi which will be recorded in the bitmap file, if a positive integer. Also used for units other than the default. If not specified, taken as 72 ppi to set the size of text and line widths.

Note however:

> By default no resolution is recorded in the file (except for BMP). Viewers will often assume a nominal resolution of 72 ppi when none is recorded. As resolutions in PNG files are recorded in pixels/metre, the reported ppi value will be changed slightly.